How do I make android EditText not selectable, but still clickable?
I have an EditText that I want users to be able to click on in order to make the cursor appear and then enable writing text. However, I don't want the user to be able to select the text (in the way that the transparent colored square appears over it to enable copying and cutting). So basically I want it to work normally with the cursor, but prevent them from selecting the text by holding it or double clicking it.
Here is the xml of the EditText:
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/scentenceEditText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:text="EditText"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="38dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="36dp" />

And here is what I tried to do to in kotlin code (in the adapter onBindViewHolder function):
holder.scentenceEditText.setTextIsSelectable(true)
holder.scentenceEditText.setTextIsSelectable(false)
holder.scentenceEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)
holder.scentenceEditText.setFocusable(true)
holder.scentenceEditText.setClickable(true)

This code makes it so that the text isn't selectable, but the problem is that then the cursor isn't visible. In that case the cursor works fine, but it needs to be visible.
If you know how to disable selecting text or how to make the cursor visible in the case I've tried, please share the solution.

holder.scentenceEditText.setTextIsSelectable(false)
holder.scentenceEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)
holder.scentenceEditText.setFocusable(true)
holder.scentenceEditText.setClickable(true)

let above code as it is and try below line in exittext of xml
    android:cursorVisible="true"

